# How do I make the main window display when I want it to during my initialization sequence

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF application I'm building.  The program displays a splash screen as it initializes.  Most of the startup sequence needs to be done in a background thread after the main window is displayed.  My problem is that the main window doesn't display when I want it to.

Here is the Window_Loaded event handler for my main window:

```
private void Window_Loaded( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e ) {
    if ( !DoInitialize() ) {
        shuttingDown = true;
        Application.Shutdown();
    }

    e.Handled = true;
}

private bool DoInitialize() {
    if ( !ReadConfiguration( Application.ConfigurationFilePath ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    Thread th = new Thread( new ThreadStart( FinishInitializing ) );
    th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); 
    th.Start();

    ClockTimer = new DispatcherTimer( TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 1 ), DispatcherPriority.Background, UpdateClock, Dispatcher );
    ClockTimer.Start();

    return true;
}
```

As you can see, except for reading the configuraton file, it doesn't do much except start the background `Thread` to finish the initialization and start a `DispatcherTimer`.  This timer is used to update a clock on the display.

What is it exactly that triggers the display of the main window?

Tony

Comment: did you make your own splash screen or are you setting the build action of your image to SplashScreen?

Comment: I set the build action of my image to SplashScreen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to execute code after the window has been rendered (shown) you can attach to the Window.ContentRendered event on your Main Window.

To answer your question the order is

- SplashScreen shown
- MainWindow Constructor (InitializeComponent())
- Window.Loaded called
- Window shown
- Window.ContentRendered called
- SplashScreen hidden

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  I had to remove the e.Handled = true; line from the end of my Window_Loaded event handler to get it to work, though.  My UI is now displayed about 5 seconds after you start the program.